# Boolean Method for checking input character

Tags: java

Here, In my code, I need to check a character with boolean value. For this, I created a boolean method and checked the character input But when I use this method in the while loop, It's getting some error. So, now what can I do for this character validation. My code looks like-

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your character: ");
        String operator = input.next();
        char c=operator.charAt(0);



        public static boolean isNotChar(char c){
            boolean returnValue;
            if(c != '+' || c != '-' || c != '*' || c != '/' || c != '^'){
                returnValue = true;
            }else{
                returnValue = false;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        boolean b1 = isNotChar(c);

        while (b1 == true){
                System.out.println("Operator doesn't match. Try again.");
                System.out.print("Enter the operator (+ - X / ^): ");
                c = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
        System.out.println("Your character is "+c);
    }
}
```

And my error like-

```
E:\java>javac Test.java
Test.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
                public static boolean isNotChar(char c){
                ^
Test.java:26: error: illegal start of type
                while (b1 == true){
                ^
Test.java:26: error: <identifier> expected
                while (b1 == true){
                         ^
Test.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
                System.out.println("Your character is "+c);
                                  ^
Test.java:31: error: illegal start of type
                System.out.println("Your character is "+c);
                                   ^
Test.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
6 errors
```

How should I make boolean method for it?

**The solution of the code is :-**

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your character: ");
        String operator = input.next();
        char c=operator.charAt(0);

        boolean b1 = isNotChar(c);

        while (b1 == false){
                System.out.println("Character doesn't match. Try again.");
                System.out.print("Enter the Character from (+ - X / ^): ");
                c = input.next().charAt(0);
                b1 = isNotChar(c);
            }
        System.out.println("Your character is "+c);
    }

    public static boolean isNotChar(char c){

        boolean returnValue;

        if(c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '*' && c != '/'){
            returnValue = false;
        }else{
            returnValue = true;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"But when I use this method in the while loop, It's getting some error"` -- I'm sure that you're seeing much more specific and informative information than just "some error". Please consider sharing this information with us.

Comment: Where do you change `b1` within the while loop? If `b1` is never changed, how will the loop ever end?

Comment: `c != '+' || c != '-'` is always true. You perhaps  mean `&&`.

Comment: You are defining a method inside your main method. You can't do that (well, you can... But if you don't know the problem here, I won't mention how you can, because you need to learn basics first)

Comment: `while (b1 == true){ ... }` will never terminate as you aren't evaluating `c` anymore to change the state of `b1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: is right, you can't nest a method within another method in Java, not like this. Please get the boolean method **outside** of your main method

Comment: thanks, @Andy Turner & @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels : I knew that but now I could not notice this mistake. Now i take boolean method outside of main method. now didn't show any error but while loop is not working.

Comment: And we've told you why it's not working -- it can't possibly stop since no where inside of it do you have `b1 = false;`. If `b1` never changes, the loop never ends. And by the way, you should change it to `if (b1) {`. And I'd change the name of that variable to something more intuitive, something that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, take the `isNotChar` method out of the main method. After that you still have 2 problems. The first is that `isNotChar` will always evaluate to true because of the if statement. You have: `if(c != '+' || c != '-' || c != '*' || c != '/' || c != '^')`. Since you use || it always evaluates to true, you probably meant to switch them all to `&&`.

Your second problem is that you never update the value of b1 that you want to test against. When you take in your new line of input you need to rerun `isNotChar` on the first character of the new input and set b1 equal to that result.

Comment: Thank for comment @A.K. : please more specific the second problem. how will be solved the second problem.

Comment: Try adding at the end of your while loop something like `b1=isNotChar(c)`. This will cause you to test this new letter again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define isNotChar() method out of the main method as it is of static context and defined under the main method.